# Is it possible to search using multiple criteria

Tags: api, openfda

Is it possible to search OpenFDA using multiple search fields. Separately both terms work but I can't figure out how to search using both at the same time.

This is what I tried that does not work to search using `rxcui` and `manufacturer_name`.

```
$ curl https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json\?search\=openfda.rxcui:860975\&search\=openfda.manufacturer_name\=NCS                                                                                  2.6.5

{
  "error": {
    "code": "BAD_REQUEST",
    "message": "Invalid parameter: openfda.rxcui:860975"
  }
}%
```

The `rxcui` by itself works

```
$ curl https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json\?search\=openfda.rxcui:860975                                                                                                                          2.6.5

{
  "meta": {
    "disclaimer": "Do not rely on openFDA to make decisions regarding medical care. While we make every effort to ensure that data is accurate, you should assume all results are unvalidated. We may limit or otherwise restrict your access to the API in line with our Terms of Service.",
    "terms": "https://open.fda.gov/terms/",
    "license": "https://open.fda.gov/license/",
    "last_updated": "2020-05-30",
    "results": {
      "skip": 0,
      "limit": 1,
      "total": 92
    }
  },
  "results": [
    ...
  ]
}
```

The `manufacturer_name` by itself works

```
$ curl https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json\?search\=openfda.manufacturer_name\=NCS                                                                                                                2.6.5

{
  "meta": {
    "disclaimer": "Do not rely on openFDA to make decisions regarding medical care. While we make every effort to ensure that data is accurate, you should assume all results are unvalidated. We may limit or otherwise restrict your access to the API in line with our Terms of Service.",
    "terms": "https://open.fda.gov/terms/",
    "license": "https://open.fda.gov/license/",
    "last_updated": "2020-05-30",
    "results": {
      "skip": 0,
      "limit": 1,
      "total": 318
    }
  },
  "results": [
    ...
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `AND` logical operator as described in the [openFDA documentation](https://open.fda.gov/apis/query-syntax/).